# iPhone 5 auto-complete Messages

Tags: iphone, auto-complete

I have a small issue, every time I type in "and", auto-complete changes that to "shut the fk up". I've searched all around and even reset in Settings -> General -> Keyboard reset

Anyone else have this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to Settings->General->Keyboard. And see if you have 'and' defined in the shortcuts.

Comment: Yes! Someone is messing with you as it would be very hard to "train" the spelling engine to perform that bizarre of a substitution.